# Starting an independent process through a new terminal

Tags: linux, shell

I've been trying to create a new keyboard shortcut that should do some stuff and then open Obsidian.

I am currently using Alacritty as my default terminal emulator and this is the script I am running on it:

```bash
#! /bin/bash

echo Doing some heavy stuff
sleep 5

echo Doing some other heavy stuff
sleep 3

echo Opening Obsidian
/home/enzo/tools/obsidian &
```

It works just fine when I execute it directly in a terminal: it prints the things it should print and then opens an independent instance of Obsidian that doesn't get closed when the terminal gets closed.

The problem is that I want to perform those tasks using a keyboard shortcut and I really need to know what is going on during the execution of the script, that is why I've put some `echo` statements in it.

So I've defined a shortcut that runs `alacritty -e my_script.sh`, which opens a new Alacritty instance and correctly executes my script, but closes Obsidian afterwards. I want the new terminal instance not to close Obsidian after getting closed.

I've also tried many (many) combinations of `nohup`, `&` and `disown`. None of them seemed to work.

`shopt` (shell options) shows that `huponexit` is set `off`, which means `SIGHUP` should not be sent for subprocesses (at least, as far as I know), and I shouldn't even had tried `nohup`. Actually, `huponexit` being set off is what is making my script perform as expected when I execute it directly in terminal.

**EDIT:** In order to make things a little bit clearer, I've made this example to demonstrate what I consider to be a successful situation:

1. Pressing some key shortcut, like `CMD + N`;
2. Seeing a new terminal instante opening and printing some important stuff;
3. Seeing Obsidian being launched and working;
4. Seeing the terminal being closed without affecting Obsidian.

What is going on? Did I miss something?

Comment: Did you try **[`tmux`](https://linuxize.com/post/getting-started-with-tmux/)**? Alacrity miht not respect `nohup`

Comment: I've tried once, but it did not work. Maybe I need to give it another try. I forgot to say that I've also tried `gnome-terminal`.

Comment: Please give this a try once: `tmux new-session -d -s my_session 'bash my_script.sh'`

Comment: Thanks for your reply. The command you provided executed the script correctely and opened Obsidian in an independent way, but did not open a new terminal instance. I really need that new terminal instance, unfortunately.

Comment: Ok I think I figured out your requirement. Please give this a try as well: `gnome-terminal -- bash -c 'tmux new-session -d -s my_session '\''bash -c '\''`. Keep the session open at last

Comment: Unfortunately, that did not work either. I've edited my question description to make things a little clearer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The obvious solution should be:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo ...
sleep 5

echo Opening Obsidian
nohup /home/enzo/tools/obsidian &
```

Alas, this doesn't work. I think that the issue is that there is a raze there, because of how `&` works.

The `&` at the end of a command actually converts the whole line into a sub-shell, so the shell starts by doing `fork()` and then it execs the command in the new process while the old one goes on running.

But with the script above, the main shell process immediately finishes and causes a `SIGHUP` in the whole process group, before the `nohup` program has a chance to start running and setting the proper signal masks. And thus the new process is aborted and does nothing.

The solution depends on how fancy you want to go.

**Solution #1**, the bad.

Just to add a pause at the end to give `nohup` a chance to run:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo ...
sleep 5

echo Opening Obsidian
nohup /home/enzo/tools/obsidian &
sleep 1
```

Naturally you have heard that synchronizing parallel tasks using delays is bad, (how much delay? are you sure `nohup` won't take more than 1 second to run?) so you may want to do it better...

**Solution #2**, the ugly.

Wait for the right process to show up. There are a variety of ways to do it. Something like this should work, depending on how `obsidian` identifies itself, that I don't know:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo ...
sleep 5

echo Opening Obsidian
nohup /home/enzo/tools/obsidian &
PID=$!
while [ -d "/proc/$PID" -a "$(< /proc/$PID/cmdline)" != "/home/enzo/tools/obsidian" ]
do
    :
done
```

Beware that that your `obsidian` command may fail to run properly so you have to check for the PID directory to exist...

**Solution #3**, the good.

I don't know if `bash` has any proper synchronization primitives, but a humble plain temporary file will do:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo ...
sleep 5

echo Opening Obsidian
T=$(mktemp)
nohup bash -c "rm \"$T\" ; exec /home/enzo/tools/obsidian" &

while [ -f "$T" ]
do
    :
done
```

Remember that `mktemp` creates an empty temporary file with a random name and returns its name.
The order between `rm` and `obsidian` doesn't matter,  because when any of that is run `nohup` has already done its magic.
The `exec` is there just to avoid having the sub-subshell hanging around doing nothing but waiting for `obsidian` to finish.

**Solution #4**, the boring.

While I was writing the previous one, it occurred to me that if you are willing to do sub-subshells and to write `nohup bash -c...` there is a pretty obvious solution:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo ...
sleep 5

echo Opening Obsidian
nohup bash -c "/home/enzo/tools/obsidian &"
```

Note that the `&` is inside the quotes, so the main shell will wait until `nohup` finishes. Mission accomplished!

Comment: After writing this question, I tried adding a pause after `nohup` as your first solutions suggest, but that didn't work either, for some reason I couldn't understand yet, even if I paused for something like a minute. But the boring solution worked perfectly. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

It's not the shell sending SIGHUP, but the terminal driver.  In particular, a non-interactive shell has job control disabled by default, so even commands started with `&` remain in the foreground process group.  That group is sent SIGHUP when the **session leader** (the shell running the script) exits.

This can be completely avoided (rather than masked as with `nohup`) by putting the command into its own session with `setsid`.  The race condition found by rodrigo plagues this approach as well, so we must wait on the process that sets the session to fork and exit.  This could be accomplished with the `bash -c '… &'` trick, but a *second* `setsid` (whose additional session is unimportant) can be used to avoid additional shell parsing:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo …
sleep …

echo Opening Obsidian
setsid -w setsid /home/enzo/tools/obsidian </dev/null &>/dev/null
```

Practically, this isn't very different from using `nohup`, but it is slightly more flexible.